# Upper triangular matrices $UT_n(\mathbb K)$ is a matrix group: is my proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, lie-groups, solution-verification

I am solving some exercises in Tapp's matrix groups for undergraduates and would be very grateful if someone could check my work (it's exercise 4.12):

> A matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb K)$ is called upper triangular if all
>    entries below the diagonal are zero. Prove that $$ UT_n (\mathbb K) =
>  \{A \in GL_n(\mathbb K) \mid A \text{ is upper triangular }\}$$ is a
>    matrix group. Show that $UT_n(\mathbb K)$ is not closed in
>    $M_n(\mathbb K)$. Is $UT_n(\mathbb K)$ compact?

Here are my thoughts on it:

That $UT_n$ is a group is clear: it is a well known fact that the product of upper triangular matrices is again upper triangular. The same holds for inverses. Therefore $UT_n$ is a group.

Furthermore, since convergence is entrywise, the limit of a sequence of upper triangular matrices is again upper triangular.

Hence if we restrict $UT_n$ to matrices of non-zero determinant then it follows that $UT_n $ is closed in $GL_n$ (because $\det$ is continuous so its limit is also non-zero).

Since given $U \in UT_n$ the matrix ${1\over k }U$ is also in $UT_n$ but the limit is zero, $UT$ is not closed in $M_{n}$.

For compactness I would argue that given $U \in UT_n$, $kU$ is also in $UT_n$. But then $UT_n$ is unbounded hence not compact.

Comment: The operation of UT is **not** the sum. Indeed, that set is not even closed under sums. What's more interesting,  though, is that the operation of sum has nothing to do with your problem :-)

Comment: If you read carefully the definition of UT that you wrote, you'll see that it only contains matrices of nonzero determinant.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Right, I see that now, thanks. I'll correct the question.

Comment: You are using n to denote the size of matrices and the index of your sequence of matrices. That's a bad idea.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Oops. Good point... I will change the index to $k$, thanks for pointing it out.